# Sublime text Auto-linting.

Tags: sublimetext2

I have a small problem in Sublime Text.

The sublime text contents are auto linting:
[image]

I am sorry to ask such questions in this forum, but cant help myself. This linting is just annoying me. In the past I have installed many packages like Anaconda and others, but I have lost the track of it..

I've checked the default setting and the package settings, but couldn't find any help.

Any help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have installed anaconda package and somehow your auto-linting is set to true.

Go to Preferences > Package settings > Anaconda > Settings-Default and set anaconda-linting to false. This should work.

Comment: Thanks man, I dont know, Somehow I missed that.... Thanks a lot,,  you are a life saver